# how to refresh parent window by using Javascript in .cs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to refresh the parent window while closing the popup window(child window).

We are calling the java script functions in code behind to refresh the parent window by using page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript().But t is working fine in IE(internet explorer) but not working in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.

In the Mozilla Firefox the pop up value is saving in the database but it is not updating into the parent page.If i did refresh manually the value is getting updating into the parent page. If i put debugger in RefreshPage()(javascript function) function in IE it is firing but not in Firefox.

The below code for call the javascript function in .cs class.

```
 page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupSave", "<script>javascript:alert('" + dsMessage.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ErrorMessage"].ToString() + "');window.open('','_self','');window.close();window.document.forms[0].submit();</script>");
```

The above code RefreshPage() is the javascript function to refresh the page

i.e.

```
function RefreshPage() { window.document.forms[0].submit(); }
```

Please help me i tried with different scenarios but no output.

instead of RefreshPage() i used different functions

like reload(),

window.opener.forms[0].submit(),

likewise but still no output anyone knows please help me.

Comment: Do you won to refresh/reload, or submit it ?, as it is change the window. to window.top.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

on submit button click run this script

```
<script language='javascript'> window.opener.frames.location='somepage.aspx';window.close();</script>
```

this will help you !!!

Comment: its OP's Choice, he can mark as answer, if it works for him .

Comment: Hi.. Ravi.. iam 100% sure it will work as i was currently using the same code in my proj...

Comment: then  why do stressing to mark as answer.  what we are doing is for knowledge. rather than "reputation.

Comment: then "Go AHEAD" for asking reputation :P :P

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to make js calls between windows.
Set 'document.domain' to the same value on both pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string closeAndRefreshScript = @"<script type='text/javascript'>                                    
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
    </script>";
    base.Response.Write(closeAndRefreshScript);
}
```